# Integration of $\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{\cos x}\cos x\sin x) \,dx$

Tags: definite-integrals

Can anyone please help me with this integration:

$$\int_0^{2\pi}(e^{\cos x}\cos x\sin x)\,dx$$
I am getting the answer as $0$ by using simply the properties of definite integral

**BUT** the answer as told by my teacher is **$2\pi$**

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: The graphics of the integrand function is symmetric with respect to the point $(\pi,0)$, hence you are right, the integral is zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the simple substitution $u = \mathrm{e}^{\cos x}$ then you'll find that $\mathrm{d}u = -\mathrm{e}^{\cos x}\sin x~\mathrm{d}x$. Moreover, $\cos x = \ln u$. When $x=0$, $u=\mathrm{e}^{\cos 0} = \mathrm{e}$ and when $x=2\pi$, $u=\mathrm{e}^{\cos 2\pi} = \mathrm{e}$. Hence
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \mathrm{e}^{\cos x}\sin x~\cos x ~ \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^0 - \ln u~\mathrm{d}u=0$$
You don't need to evaluate the integral because the upper and lower limits are the same, so the integral will evaluate to zero. If you wanted to evaluate the integral you'd see that
$$\int \mathrm{e}^{\cos x}\sin x~\cos x~\mathrm{dx} = \int - \ln u~\mathrm{d}u = u(1-\ln u) + C = \mathrm{e}^{\cos x}(1-\cos x)+C$$

Comment: I think we need to establish the existence of inetgral, that's why evaluation will be required

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Did you read all of my post? I found the indefinite integral.

Comment: I was referring to "You don't need to evaluate the integral because the upper and lower limits are the same". Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 8):

Using $$\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$$

If $\displaystyle  f(x)=e^{\cos x}\sin x\cos x,$

$\displaystyle f(2\pi+0-x)=e^{\cos(2\pi+0-x)}\sin(2\pi+0-x)\cos(2\pi+0-x)=e^{\cos x}\cos x(-\sin x)=-f(x)$

---

Also putting $\cos x=u,$

$$\int_0^{2\pi}e^{\cos x}\sin x\cos x=-\int_1^1e^u\cdot u\ du$$

The indefinite part can be managed using integration by part.

But as both the upper & the lower bounds are same, the result has to be zero

Answer (score 3):

Here's another way of looking at it:

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{2\pi}e^{\cos{x}}\cos{x}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\cos{x}}\cos{x}\sin{x}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{\cos{x}}\frac{\sin{(2x)}}{2}\,\mathrm{d}x
\end{align}$$

Comment: You really didn't need that last step.  $e^{\cos x} \cos x \sin x$ is an odd function.

Comment: @RobertIsrael True, that last step actually needed. I suppose I just tossed in that trig identity out of habit. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯